# how to apply contrast/histogram algorithm to clean the raw-gray-scale image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, infrared

I am getting this image as raw y16 format *(pointing 3 fingers in front of sensor)* after some processing on the actual data using 'opencv-python' and sensor calibration. I am getting the image as shadow only *(as seen in image)*, I am trying to get it more visible like the normal raw grayscale image (IR image). Any suggestion/solution to improve the image quality to see it more better?

The actual frame data is in yuv2 format (16bit)

1. video capture
2. video set to Y16 (raw data), convert_rgb->0, prop_format->-1
3. frame read
4. some operation on frame data

   -frame reshape to rows, cols*2

   -to unsigned int (.astype(np.uint16)

   -to big-endian format (bit shift)

   -view as unsigned int (np.uint16)
5. frame_roi crop
6. applied medianBlur
7. frame_roi bit shift (to improve visiblity)
8. applied normalization
9. applied CLAHE
10. show image

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_MSMF)

cols, rows = 340, 240
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, cols)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, rows)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('Y','1','6',' '))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))

while(cap.isOpened()):  
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    frame = frame.reshape(rows, cols*2)
    frame = frame.astype(np.uint16)               
    frame = (frame[:, 0::2] << 8) + frame[:, 1::2]
    frame = frame.view(np.uint16)   
    frame_roi = frame[:, 10:-10]
    frame_roi = cv2.medianBlur(frame_roi, 3)
    frame_roi = frame_roi << 3
    normed = cv2.normalize(frame_roi, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX,cv2.CV_8U)
    cl1 = clahe.apply(normed)
    cv2.imshow('preview',cl1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

//norm.png

[image]

Comment: please provide more information, which type of camera, what settings/code are you using to obtain your image, and which calibration parameters are you using.

Comment: @Bilal thanks for your comment. well, its thermal IR sensor which directly provides the YUV2 data format through USB and I need to do some image processing to get the visible image on host application side, in which I am using opencv-python. I updated the steps in post. Please check.

Comment: [have we discussed this question before?](https://forum.opencv.org/t/yuv2-pixel-streaming-without-image/7305) why does the picture now look like it shows fingers, when before it showed nothing? all this code won't fix up a mistaken interpretation of the data. you'll have to post some raw data again, e.g. `np.save` of the unaltered data from `cap.read`

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz yes, since I tried some more calibration to sensor side, it start showing me some shadow images as in image while using the same code flow. I'll share the 'raw data' from 'np.save'.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Please find the 'raw data' here: https://filebin.net/7azfwfapgvm517vt
Please suggest~

Comment: that is not the same data you show in that screenshot. please review [mre].

Comment: I think the data (the sensor) is simply that bad. typical approaches should work for compensating "defects" of the image sensor. dark field subtraction would be the first thing to try.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz earlier since I captured the image from streaming and later I save the raw-data, possibly it might not be the same. so I posted it again while saving image _'norm.png'_ and raw-data _'data1.npy'_ https://filebin.net/m0r2h2w1xkr367bp in parallel. hope it helps to diagnose. please suggest~

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Can I Please know, how to implement 'dark field subtraction'?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz please suggest~

Comment: @Bilal please suggest~

Comment: @Emlinux you didn't declare your **sensor (camera) type** (which brand/type of IR sensors), and you didn't share either the **code you are using** to obtain your data or your **calibration matrices**! in the absence of this useful information it will be hard to guess the problem! please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71247879/edit) your question with proper information and raw image to help find a solution.

Comment: @Bilal I posted the code brief. since this is research oriented ir qvga sensor, there is no brand. Please check the code and suggest~thanks.

Comment: @Emlinux "*there is no brand*", then how did you get image information? `340, 240` , `YUV2`, `16bit`

Comment: @Bilal as I mentioned, its research based, so there is no model/brand but there are sensor details as its ir-qvga 340,240,16bit.

Comment: "research based", explain. who fabricated the sensor? we insist on real answers.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what i mean is this is not standard ready-to-buy sensor, its similar like ir-gvga sensor, which I interfaced successfully and getting the data (gray scale) but since the image is not clear (visible), I tried to use the host application (_shared the code block in post_) to do some image process on receiving data to see the image visible. Could you please suggest some image processing way on that? Thanks.

Comment: as suggested, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark-frame_subtraction